# Remove Disks from LVM with no extent available

Tags: linux, lvm

I want to remove a physical disk from LVM. I don't seem to have free extent available in Physical Volumes

```
# pvs -o+pv_used
  PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree Used
  /dev/sdb   datavg03 lvm2 a--  <10.00g    0  <10.00g
  /dev/sdc   datavg03 lvm2 a--  <10.00g    0  <10.00g
  /dev/sdd   datavg03 lvm2 a--  <10.00g    0  <10.00g
  /dev/sde   datavg03 lvm2 a--  <10.00g    0  <10.00g
```

PV move command gives the following warning.

```
# pvmove /dev/sde --alloc anywhere
  No extents available for allocation.
```

When i do `df` command, Disks are under utilized

```
# df -Ph | grep db
/dev/mapper/datavg03-dbvol05   20G  236M   19G   2% /dbvol05
/dev/mapper/datavg03-dbvol01  4.9G   79M  4.6G   2% /dbvol02
/dev/mapper/datavg03-dbvol02  4.9G   79M  4.6G   2% /dbvol01
/dev/mapper/datavg03-dbvol03  9.8G   95M  9.2G   1% /dbvol03
```

I want o remove at least one physical disk let say /dev/sde from LVM and distribute its workload across other PV and then remove physical storage from server.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Sounds like you need to free up some space in your volume first. Can you provide output of "pvs;lvs;vgs"

Comment: You likely need to shrink or remove a logical volume to make space. Why not move the contents of 1 lv to another, then destroy the freed up one to free up some extents?